# jQuery - assign function on foreach entry object

Tags: jquery, object, onclick, mouseup, onmouseup

I've several icons with content to reveal by clicking on each icon in my header.
And when I click anywhere other than the revealed content, it closes.

Exemple :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    const header = {
        menu: {
            icon: '#menu > #menu-icon',
            wrapper: '#menu > #menu-wrapper',
        },
        wishlist: {
            icon: '#wishlist-header .heading',
            wrapper: '#wishlist-header .list',
        },
        quote: {
            icon: '#quote-header .raq-info',
            wrapper: '#quote-header .yith-ywraq-list-wrapper',
        },
        cart: {
            icon: '#cart-header .cart-info',
            wrapper: '#cart-header .woocommerce-cart-tab-container',
        }
    };

    $.each( header, ( f, el ) => {
        el.icon.on( 'click', () => {
            open_it( el );
        });
    });

    $( document ).mouseup( function( e ) {

        $.each( header, ( f, el ) => {
            if ( ! el.wrapper.is( e.target ) && el.wrapper.has( e.target ).length === 0 && el.wrapper.hasClass( 'open' ) ) {
                close_it( el );
            }
        });
    });

    function close_it( el ) {
        $( el.icon, el.wrapper ).removeClass( 'open' );
        $( '#header' ).removeClass( 'header-is-open' );
    }
    function open_it( el ) {
        $( el.icon, el.wrapper ).addClass( 'open' );
        $( '#header' ).addClass( 'header-is-open' );
    }
    
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu-icon">Menu Icon</div>
          <nav id="menu-wrapper">
            <ul>
              <li>...</li>
              <li>...</li>
              <li>...</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div>
          ...
          ...
        </div>
        <div id="icons">
          <div id="whislist-header">
            <div class="other-classes">
              <div class="heading">Wishlist Icon</div>
              <div class="list">
                <ul>
                  <li>...</li>
                  <li>...</li>
                  <li>...</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div id="quote-header">
          <div class="other-classes">
            <div class="raq-info">Quote Icon</div>
            <div class="yith-ywraq-list-wrapper">
              <ul>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cart-header">
          <div class="cart-info">Cart Icon</div>
          <div class="woocommerce-cart-tab-container">
            <ul>
              <li>...</li>
              <li>...</li>
              <li>...</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, I've a JS error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.icon.on is not a function
```

How I can assign a function to all entry object ?
So I think that assigning a mouseup function to each wrapper might not be the right solution.

What do you think is the right method?

Comment: Without looking very closely, it looks like you want `$(el.icon).on...` as your `icon` property looks like a selector and that's how you use it later on `$(el.icon, el.wrapper).`

Comment: Thanks... It's work fine with $(el.icon)... I had found a few minutes later. Sorry for this beginner's fault.
Do you have any suggestions for a cleaner code?

Comment: You *could possibly* remove some code (the need for `const header`) by moving the click/expand pair into the HTML (using `data-` attributes) then new header/menu elements would not need any code changes.  But that's a design decision rather than cleaner code.